# build html from server side c#

Tags: javascript, html, c#-2.0, server-side

I am building html at server side. The code sample is as below. My intention is to emit html like this

```
<a href="" onclick="doSomething('Test Value');">Test</a>
```

My Code Sample

```
string html="";
string param="Test Value";
html+="<a href='' onclick='"+"doSomething('"+param+"')'>Test</a>"
```

What am I doing wrong? The resultant html is bizzare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
string html="";
string param="Test Value";
html+="<a href=\"#\" onclick=\""+"doSomething('"+param+"')\">Test</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your end result for that is `<a href='' onclick='doSomething('Test Value')'>Test</a>`

The onclick portion is the one giving you the problem. You cannot use ' to enclose the value if you are trying to call a js function (I.E: doSomething in your case here)

Try this:

```
        string html=""; 
        string param="Test Value";
        html += "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"" + "doSomething('" + param + "')\">Test</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want some thing like this.

`html+=<a href="javascript:doSomething('"+param+"')">Test</a>;`

and your function is:

```
function doSomething(param) {
alert("Inside anchor tag.");//For Test
}
```

Note:But it is browser dependent.